# print lines between two occurences of a REGEX

Tags: shell, unix, sed, awk, grep

Assume I have  a text file as Follows

```
candy_box a
orange
blue
red
sweet_box a
Jelly1
jelly2
poison_box c
12a
b154
Kl213
chox_box a
Snickers;
MARS
poison_box c
k121238
asf12
as3124
```

My Script should get output like this (avoid `box C` and its Contents)

```
candy_box a
orange
blue
red
sweet_box a
Jelly1
jelly2
chox_box a
Snickers;
MARS
```

I tried to `grep  "box c"` and avoid the lines following it using Sed. But the problem is I have varying contents in box c. ie some box c contents have 3 lines , some have 4 lines.

So, How can we grep things between two occurrences of a same REGEX and Perform text operations  in the lines Contained Between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`awk` can be handy for this:

```
$ awk 'NF==2 {if (/box c$/) {f=0} else {f=1}} f' file
candy_box a
orange
blue
red
sweet_box a
Jelly1
jelly2
chox_box a
Snickers;
MARS
```

#### Explanation

- `NF==2 {if (/box c$/) {f=0} else {f=1}}` if there are two fields, do:

  - `if (/box c$/) {f=0}` if the string ends with `box c`, then switch off the flag.
  - otherwise, switch switch on the flag.
- `f` when true, it performs the default awk's behaviour --> `{print $0}`.

Comment: Works Great! 
Can You Explain it pls!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an `awk`

```
awk '/box c/{f=1;next} /box/{f=0} !f' file
candy_box a
orange
blue
red
sweet_box a
Jelly1
jelly2
chox_box a
Snickers;
MARS
```

---

Golfing the solution fedorqui posted

```
awk 'NF==2 {f=/box c$/?0:1} f' file
candy_box a
orange
blue
red
sweet_box a
Jelly1
jelly2
chox_box a
Snickers;
MARS
```

---

If data do contain line with two fields, above solution will fail.
This may be a better approach.

```
awk '/box/ {f=/box c/?0:1} f'
```

```
awk '/_box [a-z]*/ {f=/box c/?0:1} f'
```

Comment: I was about the suggest that `f=/box c$/?0:1` instead of `f=/box c$/?f=0:f=1`!

Comment: @fedorqui I did see that when I posted it, so fixed it.  Also see my last update/commment

Comment: Yes... we can certainly add many kinds of security checkings.

Comment: @fedorqui and regardless of how may, it will fail for someone :)

Answer (score 0):

```
awk '/_box .$/{p=1}/_box c$/{p=0}p' file
candy_box a
orange
blue
red
sweet_box a
Jelly1
jelly2
chox_box a
Snickers;
MARS
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -n ':a;/box c/I{:b;n;/box/ba;bb};p' file
```

If it is a line containing `box c` read on to the next line with `box` in it and test again otherwise print it.